# LDAP Authentication The specified domain either does not exist or could not be contacted

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, exception, com, ldap

I got the following error

> {"The specified domain either does not exist or could not be
>   contacted. "}

at the line

```
 Dim adResults = adSearch.FindOne.Path
```

Can anyone suggest why it is ? Seeing the below code

```
Dim ID As FormsIdentity = DirectCast(User.Identity, FormsIdentity)
    Dim ticket As FormsAuthenticationTicket = ID.Ticket
    Dim adTicketID As String = ticket.Name
    Dim adSearch As New DirectorySearcher
    adSearch.Filter = ("(userPrincipalName=" & adTicketID & ")")
    Dim adResults = adSearch.FindOne.Path
    Dim adResultsDirectory As New DirectoryEntry(adResults)
    Dim found As Boolean = False
    For Each entry In adResultsDirectory.Properties("memberOf")
        Response.Write(entry)
        Response.Write("<br/>")
        If entry = "CN=GroupName,CN=UserGroup,DC=my,DC=domain,DC=com" Then
            found = True
        End If

    Next
    If Not (found) Then
        Response.Redirect("login.aspx")
    End If
```

Answer (score 0):

Where is your domain specified?
First parameter for `DirectoryEntry` should be your AD server, something like this: `LDAP://adserver`.

Here is the code that I am using for checking whether user is authenticated in AD:

```
Dim dsDirectoryEntry As New DirectoryEntry("LDAP://" & domain, userName, password)

Dim dsSearch As New DirectorySearcher(dsDirectoryEntry)
Dim dsResults As SearchResult = dsSearch.FindOne()

If dsResults IsNot Nothing Then
    Return True
Else
    Return False
End If
```

Domain I am reading from configuration, userName and password are from login form input.